# How to use "foreign" JavaScript dependencies in Clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, clojurescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around using ["foreign" JavaScript dependencies in Clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Dependencies#bundling-foreign-javascript-code). I've read most everything Google has to offer on this topic but I still fail to understand this process. In particular, I'm interested how to depend on the [jsonld.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/) library from Clojurescript.

Some points I don't get:

1. Do you put `:foreign-libs` into deps.cljs or compiler options (e.g., `:compiler` map in project.clj)?
2. Is the value of `:file` in `:foreign-libs` interpreted as a Java resource? Where do you put the JavaScript files you use as foreign libraries? I tried putting them into `resources` and elsewhere, but all my attempts resulted in `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Steps to reproduce:

```
# Create an empty Clojurescript project
lein new figwheel jsonld

# Download jsonld.js library
cd jsonld/resources
curl -O http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsonld/0.3.15/jsonld.js

# Configure foreign libs in project.clj.
# Add the following into `:compiler` in the dev build:
# :foreign-libs {:file "resources/jsonld.js"
#                :provides ["jsonld"]}

lein figwheel # => java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Alternatively, if I provide `deps.cljs` with the following content:

```
{:foreign-libs {:file "jsonld.js"
                :provides ["jsonld"]}}
```

Then Figwheel starts, but when I call `(require '[jsonld])`, I get this error:

```
WARNING: JavaScript file found on classpath for library `jsonld`, but does not contain a corresponding `goog.provide` declaration
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: jsonld, could not locate jsonld.cljs, jsonld.cljc, or Closure namespace "jsonld" {:tag :cljs/analysis-error}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The `:foreign-libs` option takes a vector of foreign libs and not a single map.

The `:foreign-libs` option can either be supplied to the compiler directly or via a `deps.cljs` file within jars. `deps.cljs` is mostly useful when you want to package a Javascript library within a jar that other people may use — maybe useful later but not what you need right now.

> You can find more information about the compiler option [in the
>   wiki](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#foreign-libs).
>   There also is a page specifically about [using/packaging foreign
>   dependencies in
>   ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Packaging-Foreign-Dependencies).

I think in your particular example the problem is the path you're supplying as `:file`. The path is classpath-relative and the contents of the `resources/` directory are added to the classpath, meaning if you want to point to `resources/jsonld.js` in a *classpath-relative way* it's just `jsonld.js`.

PS: You can also supply URLs as `:file` and the compiler will download them for you.

Comment: Since I have seen `clojure.java.io/resource` in the stack trace leading to `java.lang.NullPointerException`, I also tried providing `:file` simply as `jsonld.js`. However, the same exception is raised that way.

Comment: Using the URL of the jsonld.js library in `:file` results in the same exception (stack trace: https://gist.github.com/jindrichmynarz/ab0e532e94a6353f9f28).

Comment: Duh, it's `:foreign-libs [{:file ...}]` — note the vector!

Comment: You're right. However, this only moves me to another stack trace: https://gist.github.com/jindrichmynarz/78411164cad89376bfa3. Do you know what's at play here?

Comment: It seems like an issue with figwheel. I'd suggest adding a new question or asking in the #figwheel channel in the clojurians.net slack team. I unfortunately don't know much about figwheel myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is the same problem without Figwheel (using Leiningen mies template), so the issue is not Figwheel-specific.